# Error while building Angular 8 project, CdkTableExporter. has no selector

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I am using "mat-table-exporter": "^9.0.0", when i serve it is working but while building project gets below error.

ERROR in Directive CdkTableExporter in .../node_modules/cdk-table-exporter/cdk-table-exporter.d.ts has no selector, please add it!

below is some snaps from package.json.

"@angular/cdk": "^8.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^8.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^8.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^8.0.0",
"@angular/material": "^8.0.0",

Comment: Resolved by using "mat-table-exporter": "^1.2.5" version.